# Selecting users alphabetically based on a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm familiar with pagination, in that I can select a group of users based on a page number like so:

```
// setup pagination
$page = 1;
$display = 5;
$start = $display * $page - $display;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE valid = 'Y' ORDER BY :username ASC LIMIT :start, :display";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':display', $display, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to do something similar only instead of a page number I have a user id. For exmaple, given the user id "3" and a display limit of "3", I want to select that user along with the user immediately before and after alphabetically (for a total of three users). I hope that makes sense..

Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses three subqueries combined with `union all`:

```
(select *
 from users
 where valid = 'Y' and username < :username
 order by username desc
 limit 1
)
union all
(select *
 from users
 where valid = 'Y' and username = :username
 order by username desc
 limit 1
)
union all
(select *
 from users
 where valid = 'Y' and username > :username
 order by username
 limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

(SELECT * FROM ints WHERE i >= 3 ORDER BY i LIMIT 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM ints WHERE i < 3 ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY i;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
```